# Sonar Qube uninstall linux

Tags: linux, sonarqube

To install sonar there is a `sonar.sh` for it. How to uninstall sonar then on linux shell?
Is there any script to remove all and don't leave any trash in the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start Sonar : `sonar.sh start`
To stop Sonar : `sonar.sh stop`
To uninstall Sonar : remove the Sonar installation directory.
That's it !

Comment: do I need root account to install sonar or can i use a non-root user?

Comment: No need for root account

Comment: I see commands like this in my bash history:
sudo /sbin/service sonar stop

Does this imply there are files elsewhere (/sbin) that also need to be removed?

Comment: and  /etc/init.d/sonar start,

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing any trouble finding the sonar directory path, In my case the `sonar.sh` file was placed at `/opt/sonarqube/bin/` location.Or you can use this command `ps aux | grep sonarqube`.

Now, you can stop the service using the command `sonar.sh stop` or permanently delete it by removing the directory.